# Add thumbnails to user groups and show user groups in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, usergroups

I have already installed a plugin called 'Groups' from [Plugin Directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/groups/)

And created main user groups called, Freelancers, Ad publishers and Members. And I created few user groups called, Photographers, Audio Producers and so on under Freelancers user group.

I want to list all the freelancers on the home page with their thumbnails.